# Custom erc20 web wallet

Tags: wallets

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to figure this out. I have a erc20 that I created. I want the website to generate a wallet that sees this new token upon creation and to be stored on the website. I can't seem to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokens are just balances in a smart contract, wallets just show this information and allow you to interact with the contract.

what you can do from the website is to display the balance of someone and implement functions using [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) (and metamask) to transfer ether and execute functions in contracts.

[This tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)) is a good start on how to do it.

Comment: Ah! Oh my goodness thank you. Been wracking my brain on this. So my host is godaddy, I have an SSH console. I am assuming that is what I would use to download node and all that?

Comment: You can install a node in your server and connect to it using web3, you can also use service like [infura](https://infura.io/) so that you do not need to install a node. The easy way, however, is to sue metamask. The users of your system can install it in their browsers (is just a plug-in) and this allows then, using the web3 code in your website to connect to the network and access the functions of your contract and balances.

Comment: Yea that would be the easy way, but seems a little unprofessional to make people use a 3rd part app. Ill check out the other things, thank you!

Comment: If I answer your question please accept it and good luck.